# Webpage, Dashboard with Cards that can be tapped on, so it directs you to the Page displayed on the Card

Tags: flutter, web-applications

I'm new to Programming and Flutter is the first Language I'm learning. I am trying to create a Dashboard, which displays 6 Elements. Creating and displaying the Elements worked for now, but I don't know how to make the Cards tappable, so that when a User clicks on it, it directs you to the Page displayed on it.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
    }
    
    class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // to get size
        var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    // style
    var cardTextStyle = TextStyle(
        fontFamily: "Open Sans",
        fontSize: 14,
        color: Color.fromRGBO(63, 63, 63, 1));

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: size.height * .3,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  image: AssetImage('')),
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 64,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 32,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d2/Crystal_Clear_kdm_user_female.svg/2048px-Crystal_Clear_kdm_user_female.svg.png'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 16,
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'User',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "Open Sans",
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'ID:4101410141',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontFamily: "Open Sans"),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GridView.count(
                      mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                      primary: false,
                      crossAxisCount: 4,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Card(
                          shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                          ),
                          elevation: 4,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 64,
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                      ''),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Description',
                                style: cardTextStyle,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),

                        Card(
                          shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                          ),
                          elevation: 4,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 64,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    ''),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'News',
                                style: cardTextStyle,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),

                        Card(
                          shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                          ),
                          elevation: 4,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 64,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Messagebox_info.svg/1200px-Messagebox_info.svg.png'),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Information',
                                style: cardTextStyle,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),

                        Card(
                          shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                          ),
                          elevation: 4,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 64,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    ''),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Registration',
                                style: cardTextStyle,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by making the desired card clickable by using **InkWell** widget, which takes the **onTap** parameter to run the desired function on click gesture and [Navigator](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) to change routes of the screens.

As shown below, you can *pass arguments* to the *target screen* and can also *return arguments* back to the *parent screen.*

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var cardTextStyle = TextStyle(
        fontFamily: "Open Sans",
        fontSize: 14,
        color: Color.fromRGBO(63, 63, 63, 1));
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: size.height * .3,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter, image: AssetImage('')),
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 64,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 32,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d2/Crystal_Clear_kdm_user_female.svg/2048px-Crystal_Clear_kdm_user_female.svg.png'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 16,
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'User',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "Open Sans",
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'ID:4101410141',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontFamily: "Open Sans"),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GridView.count(
                      mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                      primary: false,
                      crossAxisCount: 4,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  TargetPage(targetName: "Description",)));
                          },
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                            elevation: 4,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 64,
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(''),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Description',
                                  style: cardTextStyle,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  TargetPage(targetName: "News",)));
                          },
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                            elevation: 4,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 64,
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(''),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'News',
                                  style: cardTextStyle,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  TargetPage(targetName: "Information",)));
                          },
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                            elevation: 4,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 64,
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Messagebox_info.svg/1200px-Messagebox_info.svg.png'),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Information',
                                  style: cardTextStyle,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  TargetPage(targetName: "Registration",)));
                          },
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                            elevation: 4,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 64,
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(''),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Registration',
                                  style: cardTextStyle,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TargetPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TargetPage({Key? key, this.targetName = 'Default Value'}) : super(key: key);
  final String targetName ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(targetName),
        )
    ));
  }
}
```